# VBA UserForm TextBox Only Allow Numbers and Empty Text

Tags: vba, excel

In my userform I want to MsgBox if TextBox not contain Numbers or empty.
This is my code but in another case when the `TextBox = ""` Empty the MsgBox appear to me, so the issue with me is the empty TextBox.

```
Private Sub TB1_Change()
    If TypeName(Me.TB1) = "TextBox" Then
        With Me.ActiveControl
            L12.Caption = Val(TB1.Text) * Val(TB2.Text)
            If Not IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value <> vbNullString Then
                MsgBox "Sorry, only numbers allowed"
                .Value = vbNullString
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What does `MsgBox "Sorry, only numbers allowed but you entered '" & .Value & "'."` write in between `'` ?

Comment: Sorry Peh I didn't understand the msg :)

Comment: Replace your MsgBox code with the code I posted. Run your code and tell us what is in the MsgBox when your textbox is empty.

Comment: The Msg was
Sorry, only numbers allowed but you entered " word I selected it from ComboBox"

Comment: Shouldn't `With Me.ActiveControl` be `With Me.TB1` - at the moment it is using the value of the `ActiveControl` rather than the value of the `TextBox`.

Comment: I think you might want to re-visit your design. A message box popping up whenever you hit an illegal key, will be annoying as frick.

Comment: And are you changing the value of TB1 programmatically - i.e. do you change it as part of your ComboBox change code?

Comment: Dear YowE3K
Thanks you, it's working now as I need :)
I changed Me.ActiveControl to be Me.TB1

Comment: @Sagy.K - You should still rethink your design - the `TB1_Change` code will be getting executed every time the user enters a character in the textbox (so 5 times if they type "hello") or deletes a character, and it is also getting called every time your code changes the value of the textbox (e.g. initialising it).

Comment: `TypeName(Me.TB1)` will *always* be `"TextBox"`, so the boolean expression at start of this procedure is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Key Press event for this purpose.

```
Private Sub TB1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If Not IsNumeric(Chr(KeyAscii)) Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub
```

This procedure will just ignore anything you enter if it isn't a number, but you can modify both the condition and the output. For example, you might allow a decimal point to be entered, or you might wish to show a message box - perhaps only on the second try.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to allow only "Numeric" and "Blank" then the code below would deliver your needs.

```
Private Sub TB1_Change()
    if IsNumeric(Me.TB1.Value) = True or Me.TB1.Value = vbNullString then
        'Good data, nothing to MSG
    Else
        MsgBox "Your input data is not valid"
    Endif
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Comments would help create searchable content.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `AfterUpdate` event handler *instead* of the `Change` event, might also want to use the `Exit` event and cancel the exit if the user enters an invalid value:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub TB1_AfterUpdate()
    'Check whether the value is numeric or empty:
     If Not IsValNumeric(Me.TB1.Value) Then
         MsgBox "Sorry, only numbers allowed"
         Me.TB1.Value = vbNullString

     Else:
         'Do something...
         MsgBox val(TB1.Text) * val(TB2.Text)
     End If
End Sub
Private Sub TB1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'Prevents the user from EXIT the TextBox if value is not numeric/empty
    Cancel = Not IsNumeric(Me.TB1.Value)
End Sub
Private Function IsValNumeric(val$) As Boolean
    Dim ret As Boolean
    'check for numeric value only and allow empty value as a zero value
    ret = IsNumeric(val) Or Len(val) = 0
    IsValNumeric = ret
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until the user finishes their input and then test the field.

For usability, the message box should be replaced with a caption and an icon/picture like this [image] "A number must be entered here."

These would be displayed next to the text box when the input is incorrect.  Then hidden when the input is corrected.  The submission of the form can be blocked until all the errors have been corrected.

This allows the user to enter the request data and then fix any input errors.  This is better than stopping them every time they make a mistake.

The event is changed from **Change** to **Exit**.

```
Private Sub TB1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If TypeName(Me.TB1) = "TextBox" Then
        With Me.ActiveControl
            L12.Caption = Val(TB1.Text) * Val(TB2.Text)
            If Not IsNumeric(.Value) Or .Value = vbNullString Then
                MsgBox "Sorry, only numbers allowed"
                .Value = vbNullString
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

The **vbNullString** test has also been updated.